# Combine elements into a carousel in mobile view?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, slider, carousel

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2FJuP.png) are the elements that I want them to be combined into a swipeable carousel. Is there a way to do this? I just want them to turn into carousel only in mobile view.

Here is the HTML if needed. Thanks for help.

```
<div class="col-md-5 col-xs-12 d-flex justify-content-center little">
    <div class="col launch">
      <div class="row-sm-3 row-md-4 fx">
        <div class="row d-flex justify-content-center resim"><img src="css/img/Icon1.png" alt=""></div>
        <div class="row d-flex justify-content-center baslik">First 7 Days Free</div>
        <div class="row d-flex justify-content-center yazi">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut.</div>
      
      </div>
      <div class="row-sm-3 row-md-4 fx">
        <div class="row d-flex justify-content-center resim"><img src="css/img/Icon2.png" alt=""></div>
        <div class="row d-flex justify-content-center baslik">Fully Support</div>
        <div class="row d-flex justify-content-center yazi">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut.</div>
        
      </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col star">
      <div class="row-sm-3 row-md-4 fx">
        <div class="row d-flex justify-content-center resim"><img src="css/img/Icon3.png" alt=""></div>
        <div class="row d-flex justify-content-center baslik">Modern Flat Design</div>
        <div class="row d-flex justify-content-center yazi">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut.</div>
      </div>
      <div class="row-sm-3 row-md-4 fx" >
        <div class="row d-flex justify-content-center resim" ><img src="css/img/Icon4.png" alt="" id="ozel"></div>
        <div class="row d-flex justify-content-center baslik">User Friendly</div>
        <div class="row d-flex justify-content-center yazi">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut.</div>
      </div>
  </div>


  </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the only opportunity is to have both code for your grid-like display (as shown above) and for your carousel like this:

```
<!-- Code of your grid view -->
<div id="gridView">
  <div class="col-md-5 col-xs-12 d-flex justify-content-center little">
    ...
  </div>
</div>
<!-- Code of your carousel -->
<div id="carouselExampleControls" class="carousel slide mx-3 my-2" data-ride="carousel">
  ...
</div>
```

Next use [Bootstrap `display` property](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/utilities/display/#hiding-elements) to properly show and hide the containers, e.g., `d-md-none` to hide on md and wider screens and `d-none d-md-block` to hide on screens smaller than md:

```
<!-- Code of your grid view -->
<div id="gridView" class="d-none d-md-block">
  <div class="col-md-5 col-xs-12 d-flex justify-content-center little">
    ...
  </div>
</div>
<!-- Code of your carousel -->
<div id="carouselExampleControls" class="carousel slide mx-3 my-2 d-md-none" data-ride="carousel">
  ...
</div>
```

Since you are using `d-flex`, I put the extra `<div id="gridView">` around it.

Here is an [example of a Bootstrap carousel with captions](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/components/carousel/#with-captions):

```
<div id="carouselExampleCaptions" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#carouselExampleCaptions" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#carouselExampleCaptions" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#carouselExampleCaptions" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ol>
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="carousel-item active">
      <img src="..." class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
      <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
        <h5>First slide label</h5>
        <p>Nulla vitae elit libero, a pharetra augue mollis interdum.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img src="..." class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
      <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
        <h5>Second slide label</h5>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img src="..." class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
      <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
        <h5>Third slide label</h5>
        <p>Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleCaptions" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleCaptions" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
</div>
```

You can easily integrate your containers there and combine it with the above mentioned approach.

Good luck!